# Presenting UIAlertController from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add alerts to a custom `UITableViewCell` to present an `UIAlertView` I need to call presentViewController from `UIViewController`.  However, I am unaware of how to gain access to the current `UIViewController` instance from the `UITableViewCell` class.  The below code is my attempt to do this with an extension.

I get this error

> Expression resolved to unused function.

```
extension UIViewController
{

    class func alertReminden(timeInterval: Int)
    {
        var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refresh", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            Alarm.createReminder("Catch the Bus",
                timeInterval: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(timeInterval * 60)))
        }))

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            println("Handle Cancel Logic here")
        }))

        UIViewController.presentViewController(refreshAlert)


    }
}

class CustomRouteViewCell: UITableViewCell {
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use this extension to find the viewController that present the cell

```
extension UIView {
var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.nextResponder()
        if parentResponder is UIViewController {
            return parentResponder as! UIViewController!
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Or use `rootViewController` to Present:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 4.2 Update**

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if parentResponder is UIViewController {
                return parentResponder as? UIViewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Or use `rootViewController` to Present:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How exactly can I use this extension?

Answer (score 18):

Try to replace to this line of code:

**Swift 2**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3**

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks friends for your awesome effort.

Comment: This didn't work for by since my tableview was also in a navigation controller. I was able to present using if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
            topController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

Answer (score 15):

Another way to do this is to declare a protocol and a delegate property in the table view cell class, set the controller as the cells delegate and implement the protocol in the controller which is able to present the alert view controller.

Comment: I think this approach is the cleanest.

Comment: But if you want to manipulate some controls within the tableviewcell after the alert is dismissed you won't have access to them

Comment: Hey, I want to use your suggestion but not understanding fully. I created a protocol and declared the delegate property in the cell class. I got lost when you said: "set the controller as the cells delegate and implement the protocol in the controller".  Also what is the func do I have to create in the protocol? I used "func alert(vc: UIViewController)". Will that work? thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Leo's solution worked for me. I've used it to present an AlertView from a Custom collection view cell.

Update for Swift 3.0:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if parentResponder is UIViewController {
                return parentResponder as! UIViewController!
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using a protocol, and delegate, using this method will give you the opportunity to not only present alerts but could give you a better interaction with your view controller in case that you need it on the future. For example:

```
protocol alerts: class{

    func presentAlert(title:String, message:String)

}
```

Then in your tableViewCell you'll create something like:

```
var alertsDelegate : alerts? 

//And whenever you need to present a message call something inside the cell like:

alertsDelegate?.presentAlert(title:"Your title", message:"Your message")
```

Then in your viewController, firstly set your viewController as alerts

```
class yourClassName : ViewController, alerts {

    //And add the functions of the protocol
    func presentAlert(title:String, message:String){
        //This is the function that'll be called from the cell
        //Here you can personalize how the alert will be displayed

    }
}
```

Second, set the delegate for the cell in the "cellForRowAt" method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier") as! yourCellClass

    cell.alertsDelegate = self

}
```

And just like this you can create multiple functions that adapt your need in relation with communication with your viewController or viewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Must be declared protocol and their delegate property in `CustomTableViewCell Class and called these properties at the place of UIAlertViewController`, and implement these protocol properties in `UIViewController`.