# present UIAlertController from a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols, uialertcontroller

I`d like to present UIAlertController by tapping a menu button on a cell

```
class FeedViewCell: UITableViewCell {
// some code...

 lazy var menuButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

@objc func menuTapped() {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
            print("tap dismiss")
        }))
        
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Follow", style: .default, handler: { action in
            print("tap follow")
        }))

     present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    }
}
```

and here's a FeedViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! FeedViewCell
        return cell
    }
```

However im getting the error "Cannot find 'present' in scope"

Im not sure how to present it using a delegate and protocol. Please help me out

Comment: Only a view controller can present alerts. Add a callback closure, move the action into the controller and present the alert from there. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494

Comment: Do it with a view controller.  Add a closure inside the cellForRowAt delegate method.

Comment: You can find some of the ways is below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483104/presenting-uialertcontroller-from-uitableviewcell/30483636

Answer (score 2):

Ivan's approach of hunting up the responder chain for a UIViewController would work, but I suggest a different approach.

Modify your `FeedViewCell` class to have an Optional viewController property:

```
class FeedViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Note that the pointer to the view controller should be weak
    // To avoid a retain cycle, as pointed out by Matt.
    weak var viewController: UIViewController? = nil
    // some code...
}
```

And modify your IBAction method:

```
@IBAction func menuTapped() {
        // Make sure `viewController` is not nil.
        guard let viewController = viewController else {
           print("No view controller found. Exiting.")
           return
        }
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
            print("tap dismiss")
        }))
        
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Follow", style: .default, handler: { action in
            print("tap follow")
        }))
     // Change your code to send the `present(_:animated:)` message to 
     // the cell's `viewController`.
     viewController.present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And then in your view controller that configures FeedViewCell cells, set the viewController property of the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // Replace with the correct reuse identifier
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: yourIdentifier) as? FeedViewCell else {
       return UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell.viewController = self // Or, if the data source is not the main view controller for the window, pass in some other view controller.
}
```

Comment: Retain cycle here?

Comment: True that. Yes, the pointer back to the view controller should be weak.

Answer (score 1):

For present alert inside cell, you should get parent controller. Alert controller can be present only on other parent controller.

Lets do it. First, add extension. It allow get controller which view using:

```swift
public extension UIView {

    var viewController: UIViewController? {
        weak var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now you can inside cell get controller. Lets do it:

```swift
@objc func menuTapped() {
   // You added alert here, your code
   guard let parentController = self.viewController else { return }
   parentController.present(actionSheet, animated: true)
}
```

That all.

Comment: That approach will usually work, but it's fragile. If you have multiple parent view controllers in your view controller hierarchy your code might select the wrong one . It would be better to give the cell a viewController property and have the parent view controller populate it.

Comment: I disagree. It is not fragile. We know the desired class.

Comment: this worked for me very fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your whole approach is wrong; it's no business of a cell to boss view controllers around. However, if you insist, use this utility:

```
extension UIResponder {
    func next<T:UIResponder>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
        let r = self.next
        if let r = r as? T ?? r?.next(ofType: T.self) {
            return r
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now

```
self.next(ofType: FeedViewController.self)?.present...
```