# Cannot use UIAlertController inside a prototype cell in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with a prototype cell. Inside this prototype cell I have a button which I want to use to report a comment.

I tried to use an example UIAlertController but it gives me the following error.

```
Value of tableViewCell has no member present.
```

And also this error:

```
"nil" requires a contextual type.
```

I used the code below also somewhere else and it worked fine.

What exactly did I do wrong here? I already googled the error types but don't find anything that could help me.

```
func displayAlert() {
           // Declare Alert message
           let dialogMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "Test", preferredStyle: .alert)
           
           // Create OK button with action handler
           let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
               print("Ok button tapped")
               self.deleteRecord()
           })
          
           
           //Add OK and Cancel button to dialog message
           dialogMessage.addAction(ok)
           
           // Present dialog message to user
           self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
           
       }
    func deleteRecord()
        {
            print("Delete record function called")
        }
```

Comment: you must delegate action to parentView and the parent view will display the alert.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting UIAlertController from UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483104/presenting-uialertcontroller-from-uitableviewcell)

Comment: @cristian_064 how can I do that?

Comment: @HangarRash it seems the issue is the same but I don't understand the solution. And what exactly to do. The answers also are about 7 years old.